# Error while connecting to SQL Server Management Studio in server name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL Server. I have recently installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio on my computer. After starting the SQL Server Management Studio, I was asked to give a server name to connect to. I tried connecting it with `.\SQLExpress` but it is giving me the following error:

> Cannot connect to .\SQLExpress
>   Additional infromation:
>   A network related or instance specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL server.The server was not found or was not accessible.Verify that the instance name is correct ant that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections(provider-SQL Network Interfaces,error:26-Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)(Microsoft SQL Server)

What should I do to get connected?

Comment: Have you enabled TCP/IP for the instance?

Comment: or if its a named instance, start the sql browser service.

Comment: Did you install **just** Management Studio, or did you also install the **SQL Server Express core engine** ?

Comment: @marc_s I just installed Management Studio

Comment: Then you'll need to install that **actual database engine**, too! Just Management Studio is just that - **JUST** the management tools - but no database to connect to!

Comment: Download the **actual** database engine from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1695 - use 32- or 64-bit as appropriate, and then install it. Once that's done, **THEN** you can connect to it using Management Studio ...

Comment: @marc_s I tries downloading from the link you gave me but at the end of the installation it is giving me this error-wait on the database engine recovery handle failed.check the SQL server error log for potential